# Appium integration with Teamcity

Tags: android, selenium, webdriver, teamcity, appium

I am using `Appium JAVA (Webdriver, Selenium)` to test Android applications, but i could not find any tutorials how to integrate Appium test with `TeamCity CI` which implement in Linux enviroment (or any). Can anyone suggest the way to build up Appium+Teamcity working to implement tests after commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been looking for the same integration. There are two ways to achieve this.

1. Saucelabs is a Cloud platform to run the browser based or mobile based tests. There is a sauce labs runner that connects Teamcity with Saucelabs. Here is the link for that. https://saucelabs.com
2. Other option is to use NUNit runners to integrate Appium / Selenium with Teamcity using dot net frameworks. Here is the reference link that may help you get started. NUnit Plugin for Teamcity - https://github.com/JetBrains/integration-tests-vm-scripts.

While first option seems to be little costly even to start, second option did not have much documentation to start with.